# Getting values from a child class

Tags: c#, list

I have two classes:

```
public class ShopClass
    {
        public string shop_id { get; set; }
        public List<CurrencyAmount> amount { get; set; }
    }


public class CurrencyAmount
    {
        public string currency { get; set; }
        public int? amount { get; set; }
    }
```

I can add values to the class ShopClass like this:

```
ShopClass shop = new ShopClass();
        shop.shop_id = "100";
        List<CurrencyAmount> ca = new List<CurrencyAmount>();
        ca.Add(new CurrencyAmount() { currency = "USD", amount = 1000});
        shop.amount = ca;
```

I can get the value of shop_id like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(shop.shop_id);
```

But how can I get the value of the amount?

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Having a list of currency amount implies that you have many amounts for every shop. So if you want to get an amount from that shop you need to specify which one (using an index)

Comment: Use foreach loop for it get the values of list of currency item .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
foreach (var v in shop.amount)
{
    Console.WriteLine(v.currency + " " + v.amount);
}
```

Or alternatively, you can avoid string concatenation (thanks PC Luddite) and use:

```
foreach (var v in shop.amount)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", v.currency, v.amount);
}
```

This snippet will print out all of the values in `shop.amount`. Since `shop.amount` refers to a list, you can't get the values by using `Console.WriteLine(shop.amount)`, as this will just print out a reference to the list. Instead, you need to iterate through all of the items in `shop.amount` in order to get their values.

Comment: This will print _<namespace>.CurrencyAmount_ not the values of every single currency and amount properties in the list

Comment: Thanks for spotting that!

Comment: @helencrump `Console.WriteLine()` can take a format string, so no need to using string concatenation (which in some cases can be extremely inefficient) `Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", v.currency, v.amount);`

Comment: I know - it's a bad habit that I'm trying to lose.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "the" amount, you have a list of amounts. So you need to iterate or project the items in the `amount` property, for example using a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (var amount in shop.amount)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", amount.currency, amount.amount);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your example can easily be reduced to a dictionary for direct lookup.  I'm assuming you're looking to find the value for a specific currency and not print all values.

Store currencies and their values.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ShopClass
{
    public ShopClass()
    {
        Amounts = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    }

    public string ShopID { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, int> Amounts { get; private set; }

    public void AddAmount(string currency, int amount)
    {
        if (Amounts.ContainsKey(currency))
        {
            Amounts[currency] = amount;
        }
        else
        {
            Amounts.Add(currency, amount);
        }
    }

    public int? GetAmount(string currency)
    {
        if (Amounts.ContainsKey(currency))
        {
            return Amounts[currency];
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void PrintAmounts()
    {
        foreach (var currency in Amounts.Keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}: {2}", ShopID, currency, GetAmount(currency));
        }
    }
}
```

Print currency values.

```
ShopClass shop = new ShopClass();
shop.ShopID = "100";
shop.AddCurrency("USD", 1000);
shop.PrintAmounts();
```